# Copying updated Files between Networks

Tags: copy, rsync

Is there a way that I can copy updated files only from one network to another? The networks aren't connected in anyway, so the transfer will need to go via CD (or USB, etc.)

I've had a look at things like `rsync`, but that seems to require the two networks to be connected.

I am copying from a Windows machine, but it's going onto a network with both Windows and Linux machines (although Windows is preferable due to the way the network is set up).

Answer (score 1):

you can rsync from source to the use-drive, use the usb-drive as a buffer, and then rsync from the usb-drive to the target. to benefit from the rsync algorithm and reduce the amount of copied data you need to keep the data on the usb-drive between runs.